# Creating a global npm package

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I found this article that talks about creating global packages: https://bretkikehara.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/nodejs-creating-your-first-global-module/

So I've got a bin value declared in my `package.json` like this:

```
"bin": {
    "my-server": "./bin/start-server.js"
  }
```

And in `start-server.js` I have a reference to `../server.js` which is what I run to start my express server up. After I do an `npm install -g` in my project folder and run `my-server`it works just fine, however when I navigate out of the project folder and run `my-server` the server seems to start, but none of my stylesheets or client-side javascript includes are showing up.

In my `server.js` file I'm defining these paths like this:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Is there a different way I should be setting this up so that no matter where someone calls `my-server` from it has the correct path to the stylesheets?

Comment: Did you try using `__dirname + "/../server.js"`? It would seem that your code depends on pwd being the dir of the module.

Comment: Do you mean inside of `start-server.js`? If so, that did not work.

Comment: did you try fs.readFile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer to this out. In my `server.js` file I had to add `__dirname` to the `express.static()` expression. So this is what it looks like:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This makes it work just fine so I can call `my-server` from anywhere after doing `npm install -g`